How to handle unathorized API calls using an AuthorizationHandler in ASP.NET Core
I have an ASP.NET Core v8.0.5 application with OpenIdConnect enabled. There are minimal API endpoints which are secured using a custom AuthorizationHandler to check the logged in user has appropriate permissions to execute the API request.
This is all working except for one small detail. When I request the API from my Angular client without permission ASP.NET forces a 302 redirect to the AccessDenied route which causes the client API to fail. I have code in my error handler to handle a 401 so the app can gracefully redirect to an Access Denied route but I cannot get a 401 returned to my app?
Can anybody suggest how I can control the response code returned?

403 (AccessDenied) and 401 (Unauthorized). Please edit your question and state clearly, what code you are getting currently and what code you would like to have instead. Also, please show us some code, Startup or Program would be good place to start. Especially, code where you configure request pipeline with calls such as builder.AddAuthorization().

@Prolog sorry I resolved it a minute after you posted, I've posted the code below to help anybody else in the future.

Got to the bottom of it in the end, see code below which is added at startup to override the response status.
builder.Services
...
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "__BlinkAuth";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
                    {
                        context.Response.Clear();
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                };
            })
...

